# How do I change the state of the data inside an array in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

My Users table and ProductInfo table have a 1:N relationship.

The user table contains all the information of the productInfo table. I want to change the productUseYn state from true to false in Users' ProductInfo.

++ vue.js

```
      <button @click="updateProductUseYn(false)" class="badge badge-warning" id="buttonDel">
          OK
      </button>
```

++ vue.js (script)

```
updateProductUseYn(status) {
  var data = {
    id: this.currentUser.id,
    username: this.currentUser.username,
    email: this.currentUser.email,
    password: this.currentUser.password,
    roles: this.currentUser.roles,
    delYn: this.currentUser.delYn,
    productInfo: this.currentUser.productInfo,
    productUseYn: status
  };

  UserDataService.update(this.currentUser.id, data)
    .then(response => {
      this.currentUser.productInfo.productUseYn = status;
      console.log(response.data);
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.log(e);
    });
},
```

++ Users Table
[Users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1Yeu.png)

++ProductInfo Table
[ProductInfo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKT3O.png)

++ console window
[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQ9Bb.png)

As you can see from the console, clicking the button does not cause the state change I wanted. What is the problem?

++) Edit

```
updateProductUseYn(status) {
  var data = {
    id: this.currentUser.id,
    username: this.currentUser.username,
    email: this.currentUser.email,
    password: this.currentUser.password,
    roles: this.currentUser.roles,
    delYn: this.currentUser.delYn,
    productInfo: {
      productUseYn: status,
    }
  };

  UserDataService.update(this.currentUser.id, data)
    .then(response => {
      this.currentUser.productInfo = status;
      console.log(response.data);
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.log(e);
    });
},
```

++ Network window
[Network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kHiC.png)

Comment: make sure you place `updateProductUseYn(status)` function in `methods` property

Comment: Yes. updateProductUseYn(status) is in methods. The code above is updateProductUseYn(status) in methods.

Answer (score 4):

consider from your console image you attach, have you change your `data` variable like this:

```js
var data = {
    id: this.currentUser.id,
    username: this.currentUser.username,
    email: this.currentUser.email,
    password: this.currentUser.password,
    roles: this.currentUser.roles,
    delYn: this.currentUser.delYn,
    productInfo: { 
       ...this.currentUser.productInfo,
       productUseYn: status
    }
};
```

technique above, we use `spread operator`. this is common usage in javascript for mutating an object.

Comment: Thanks for the good point. I have posted fixes and new errors above. Can you check it?
I want to fix this with productInfo: {
productInfo: this.currentUser.productInfo
} Or I tried putting in other data, but I got a problem.

Comment: What a problem? make sure when you mutating property of an object, you must use `spread operator` or make sure you also copy all previous data

Comment: All of the problems have been resolved. Thank you so much :)